# How to draw points obtained from an array in for loop with animation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, core-animation, calayer

I can draw points with code below, but I need to draw every point one by one with animation. When I try this, all points appear on the screen only after the for loop ends.
I did some research but I could not figure out why these points are not drawing one by one in the for loop. `singerData` is an array which has x values of points.

```
-(void)drawDotGraphForUser
{    
    UIView *viewAnimationUser = [[UIView alloc]init];
    viewAnimationUser.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100);

    for (int i = 0; i<singerPitchDataSize; i++)
    {
        CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
        NSAssert1(layer != nil, @"failed to create CALayer #%i", i);

        layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:1 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
        layer.frame = CGRectMake(i+1, singerData[i], 1.0, 1.0);
        NSLog(@"GraphUser= %d=%f",i,singerData[i]);

        NSLog(@"MSprites=%@",mSprites[i]);

        CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
        pathAnimation.duration = 5;
        pathAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        pathAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:singerPitchDataSize];

        [layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
        [viewAnimationUser.layer addSublayer:layer];
        [self.view addSubview:viewAnimationUser];

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running it from the main thread?

Comment: @Mikael yes i do. i simply call this method like that [self drawDotGraphForUser];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all appearing to be happening at the same time because your animations are being sent to another thread automatically extremely quickly. If you want them to appear one by one you will need to send them to add them to the subview slower by adding a timer at the end of your function or you will need to listen for the animation to end to trigger the next one.